# importing pygame in Intellij IDEA

Tags: python, import, intellij-idea, pygame

I use intellij idea plug in for python developing. I want to import pygame module to my project, but everytime I get error "ImportError: No module named 'pygame'". I tried to add the pygame lib folder to dependencies but it didn't work, I also added it to library but it didn't work either. Could anyone help me with this issue.

Thanks

Comment: I haven't used Intellij IDEA, but I think your problem is similar to what happens with Sublime Text 2: The Python interpreter you use in the IDE is not the same you have in your path. You can confirm it with `import site;print(site.getsitepackages())` and see if it is different than the one where you have installed Pygame.

Comment: Solution by A.Rodas worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to install the pygame lib to your python directory, but you might have to make your python 32 bit for that to work dunno how it works on windows. On mac though there are several tutorials.